# Why can import smartsheet not be resolved?

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I have installed the smartsheet python sdk with `pip3 install smartsheet-python-sdk` (using Python 3.10.5). I believe it was successful because if I do it again, or even try to upgrade, I see "Requirement already satisfied" for all the requirements. Still, `import smartsheet` cannot be resolved by Pylance. I have also already set the access token and initialized the client.

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Python expert, but a minute of Googling (search phrase = `import cannot be resolved by pylance`) shows lots of info about others having this issue (not with the Smartsheet SDK specifically, but with other packages). I'd suspect this is a generic VS(Code) / Python config issue, not a problem with the Smartsheet SDK.

In particular, the answers described in these fairly recent Stack Overflow posts seem promising:

- [Import could not be resolved/could not be resolved from source Pylance in VS Code using Python 3.9.2 on Windows 10 Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486207/import-could-not-be-resolved-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-pylance-in-vs-cod).
- [VS/Pylance warning: import "module" could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68887729/vs-pylance-warning-import-module-could-not-be-resolved)