# Pylance - Unresolved import warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm using VSCode. Although my code runs as expected, I'm getting linting errors.

The code:

```py
import tensorflow.keras as keras
```

The error: `Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolved`.

I've looked at other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322120/vscode-import-x-could-not-be-resolved-even-though-listed-under-helpmodules) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68887729/vs-pylance-warning-import-module-could-not-be-resolved). Followed the answers carefully, they did not help.

I've tired to follow the [official troubleshhoting guide](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings).
Based on that I updated my `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/api/_v2/keras"
    ]
}
```

I got this directory from the following code:

```py
import tensorflow.keras as keras
print(keras.__file__)
```

Output: `/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/api/_v2/keras/__init__.py`

At this point I'm completely stuck.

- I've tried to user parent folders, nothing happened.
- Restarted everything, still nothing.

Comment: What is the solution?  I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Importing keras directly works for me: `import keras`